# Using separate server for notifications

Tags: php, node.js

I have an application that uses php for REST API calls. I want to include a notification system into the application. Can I use a nodejs server for the notification part? Both the servers will access the same database.

I want to use nodejs for notification because I can use socket.io with it.

Is it ok to use a separate server like this?

Comment: Websockets are no specific to NodeJs in any way. They have implementations for a lot of programming languages. https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io for PHP. And to come back to your question, yes it is possible. But if possible that doesn't mean it's the best solution.

Comment: Yes, you can use separate servers for that, there isn't any kind of restricting, just It will up to you to manage how your app interact with both server

Comment: @VladNeacsu so there's no advantage to using nodejs?